# Getting Bad Request error while running tests in newman

Tags: postman, newman

I am trying to run few tests that works fine in Postman but same are failing in newman with Bad request Error.

```
POST : https://{{API_Host}}/api/Context/CreateContext
```

Headers

```
[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""},
{"key":"Accept-Encoding","value":"deflate, gzip;","description":""},
{"key":"Ocp-Apim-Trace","value":"true","description":""},
{"key":"Ocp-Apim-Subscription -Key","value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","description":""},
{"key":"Authorization","value":"Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","description":""}]
```

Request:

```
{
      "ServiceContext": {
    "ContextId": "00000000-0000-000",
    "InstanceProvider": {
        "Name": "IT",
        "Version": "1.0"
    },
    "SchemaProvider": {
        "Name": "Group",
        "Version": "Version1"
    },
    "ServiceProvider": {
        "Name": "Service",
        "Version": "Version1"
    },
    "App": {
        "AppName": "APP",
        "AppVersion": "1.0"
    },
    "Operator": {
        "OperatorId": "xxxx",
        "OperatorUserId": "xxxx",
        "OperatorUserName": "xxxx",
        "OperatorUserDisplayName": "xxxx",
        "UserName": "xxxxx",
        "OperatorFurtherInfoKeys": []
    },
    "SystemEnvironment": {
        "ApplicationMode": "xxxx"
    }
}
```

}

[image: NewMan Results] [image: Postman Results]

Comment: Save your request in the Postman and export the collection along with the environment again to the Collections and Environments folder respectively to reflect the changes.